FreeCAD export stl file to glb
I am very new to FreeCAD. I am building a web based app to view STEP and STL CAD files. So far I am importing STEP files into FreeCAD via the cli and exporting to .glb and then showing them in Google . This work really well. However I can not get the export to work for STL files. I get a file but it is almost empty save for a header...
glTF "generator":"Open CASCADE Technology [www.opencascade.com]"
plus a bit more
import FreeCAD
import FreeCADGui
import FreeCAD, Part
import Part
import FreeCAD, Mesh
import Mesh
import Import
import ImportGui
import math
import stl
from stl import mesh

FreeCADGui.showMainWindow()
mw=FreeCADGui.getMainWindow()
mw.hide()
pics = "test.sp"

Mesh.open(pics)
obj=Mesh.read(pics)
doc = FreeCAD.newDocument()
Mesh.show(obj)

shape=App.ActiveDocument.ActiveObject.Mesh
doc = App.newDocument('Doc')
pf = doc.addObject("Mesh::Feature","MyShape")

ImportGui.export([pf], "test.glb")

